# Firebase+Javascript Convert anonymous account to permanent - Error: response is not defined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I'm trying to build a site where the user can first login anonymously using firebase and then convert his account to permanent by signing in with facebook. I'm following the instructions given at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth but i'm getting the following error "Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined". I also tried converting the account using Google Sign in but then i get the error "googleUser is not defined". What am i doing wrong?

This is my code:-

```
  <html>
  <body>
    <button onclick = "anonymousLogin()">Anonymous Signin</butto>
    <button onclick = "facebookSignin()">Facebook Signin</button>
    <button onclick = "facebookSignout()">Facebook Signout</button>
  </body>


 <script>
    function anonymousLogin(){
          firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().catch(function(error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code; console.log(errorCode)
            var errorMessage = error.message; console.log(errorMessage)
          });
     }

    function facebookSignin() {
     var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

     var credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(
        response.authResponse.accessToken);

     auth.currentUser.link(credential).then(function(user) {
       console.log("Anonymous account successfully upgraded", user);
      }, function(error) {
      console.log("Error upgrading anonymous account", error);
     });
    }

  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: which part of your code is generating that error?

Comment: This part
var credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(
        response.authResponse.accessToken);

Comment: see how you pass `response.authResponse.accessToken` as the argument ... what is `response`? You've not shown any code that creates a variable called `response`

Comment: i'm not creating the variable 'response'. I've just copy pasted that code from the firebase documentation. I assume firebase processes it itself?

Comment: the documentation isn't complete code -

Answer (score 1):

okay i found a solution. Apparently converting from anonymous to facebook user needs you to find the token yourself. I found this workaround.

```
 var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
 firebase.auth().currentUser.linkWithPopup(provider)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `response` here refers to the event that Facebook login passes to the callback. [Facebook traditionally calls this `response`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web), but [our Github sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/auth/facebook-credentials.html#L81) calls it `events`. The name of course isn't important, but you're not declaring it for your callback.

```
function facebookSignin(response) {
 var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

 var credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(
    response.authResponse.accessToken);
```

Also see https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/auth/facebook-credentials.html#L81

Comment: Tried that. Getting this error now -
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'authResponse' of undefined